# Download images from URL Python

Tags: python

I have problem with my script when i try download images from web url. It works on other page (offex.pl) but in my shop images are not working.
i just have all files but i can't open Files

my code:

```
import os
import time
import requests
from termcolor import colored

def get_folder(url):
    all_folders= os.path.dirname(url)
    folder=os.path.basename(all_folders)
    return folder
def filename(url):
    file=url[url.rfind("/") + 1:]
    return file

def download(link):
    error = []
    ok = 0
    fail = 0


    root_folder = get_folder(link)
    path = "{}/{}".format("download", root_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    url = link
    file = filename(link)

    result = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    completeName = os.path.join("download", root_folder, file)
    print(completeName)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        image = result.raw.read()
        open(completeName, "wb").write(image)
        ok += 1
        succes = "{} {} {}".format(ok, colored("Pobrano:", "green"), url)
        print(succes)

        time.sleep(1)

    else:
        found_error = "{} {}".format(colored("Brak pliku!:", "red"), url)
        print(found_error)
        fail += 1
        error.append("ID:{} NUMBER:{} link: {}".format(id, url))
    with open("log.txt", "w") as filehandle:
        for listitem in error:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
    print(colored("Pobrano plików: ", "green"), ok)
    print(colored("Błędy pobierania: ", "red"), fail)

img_url="https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg"


download(img_url)
```

What Im doing wrong?

for example (`https://offex.pl/images/detailed/11/94102_jeep_sbhn-8h.jpg`) download OK

but for my shop url `https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use requests module,you can use this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg")
with open('./Image.jpg','wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: @SmallAtom You can read it from requests documents.`response.content` will return the binary content.So you can write it to your file directly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the URL which you are using to download. Its not an issue, but a difference from other URL you have mentioned.

Let me explain

The URL https://offex.pl/images/detailed/11/94102_jeep_sbhn-8h.jpg returns an image as response with out any compression.

[image: Response]

On the other hand, the shop URL https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg returns the image with `gzip` compression enabled in the headers.

[image: Response for UR]

So the raw response you get is compressed with gzip compression. You can decompress the response with gzip, if you know the compression is always gzip like below

```
import gzip
import io

image = result.raw.read()
buffer = io.BytesIO(image)
deflatedContent = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer)
open("D:/sample.jpg", "wb").write(deflatedContent.read())
```

Or you can use alternative libraries like `urllib2` or similar ones, which takes care of decompression. I was trying to explain why it failed for your URL , but not for other. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: But OP can not open the Image file,not the problem of gzip.

Comment: The image content you download with .raw stream is not deflated. Storing that content as file will make the file corrupted.

Comment: I never said your code will not work!!!. I tried to explain what went wrong in the person's code. That is definitely the problem of gzip. If he still wants to work with streams instead of direct read ( not recommended for large files) , he will have to use a different way!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
import urllib2

def download_web_image(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    img = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img)

download_web_image("https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg")
```

It is working for your URL. I think the issue is with the request response of the used library.

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image

fileRequest = requests.get("https://sw19048.smartweb-static.com/upload_dir/shop/misutonida_ec-med-384-ix.jpg")
doc = Image.open(BytesIO(fileRequest.content))
doc.save("newFile.jpg")
```